# SQL to SELECT the last record for an account on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table like below

```
id transaction    value  date       account number
1                 5      05/01/17   AA1
2                 3      05/02/17   AA2
3                 7      05/01/17   AA3
4                 3      05/03/17   AA2
5                 5      05/02/17   AA1
6                 3      05/02/17   AA5
7                 5      05/03/17   AA1
8                 3      05/04/17   AA2
9                 5      05/04/17   AA1
10                3      05/02/17   AA4
11                5      05/05/17   AA1
12                3      05/06/17   AA2
13                5      05/05/17   AA1
14                3      05/07/17   AA2
15                5      05/07/17   AA1
16                5      05/01/17   AA6
17                3      05/08/17   AA2
```

I want to select the last transaction record for each account

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: I am usng MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
select t1.*
from table_name as t1,
(select account_number, max(id) as id from table_name group by account_number) as t2
where t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Makes logical sense but MySQL has errors on that syntax on (select acc_number....). It just seems not to accept t2 as the second table.

Comment: Make sure you put a comma after t1. I ran this in MySQL and it worked for me.

Comment: @edy.devs Could you let me know if this worked for you?

Comment: no. it didn't work. used java to loop through the records and get the one I want for each account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the account number. see below

```
CREATE TABLE #t (id int, value  DECIMAL(18,2), date DATETIME, account_number VARCHAR(50))

SELECT  T1.*
FROM    #T T1
       INNER JOIN (  SELECT account_number, MAX(id) id
                     FROM  #T 
                     GROUP BY account_number  ) T2
               ON T2.account_number = T1.account_number
               AND T2.id = T1.id
```

Comment: This can also be written using `IN` and a subselect.

Comment: I wrote the sql for Microsoft sql server, but Is think its ANSI compliant with the exception of the syntax for temporary table creation. In MYSQL you would use the temporary key word

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fields FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: You should add a auto increment field which is count or monitoring your field record .

Comment: Could you please tell us why @RedDevil ?

Comment: This returns only  a single row, not the last transaction **for each account**

Comment: You should use group by keyword . For more details i want to see your table structures . Can you update your question ?|and provide sql code .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY DESC
```

Comment: This will only return a single row, not one row for each account

Comment: Hi Edy, could you mark one of the answers as correct if one of them was helpful? Tks

Answer (score 0):

if your db is ordered(I assume this) try this

```
SELECT * FROM  TABLE WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: This returns only a single row, not one one row for each account.

Comment: will not work because i have a couple of account numbers!